# Does Azure load balancer support HTTP/2?

Tags: azure, nginx, http2, azure-virtual-network

Azure Web Apps currently doesn't suppport HTTP/2: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9552936-enable-http-2-on-azure-web-apps.

What about VMs? If have an Ubuntu VM running nginx > 1.9.5, I could use HTTP/2.

But how will the Azure load balancer and https endpoint behave?

Answer (score 3):

Load Balancer is protocol agnostic and will pass through any TCP or UDP application, and this includes HTTP/2.

(I'm product manager for Azure Load Balancer).

Answer (score 2):

## 2018 answer: yes, using Application Gateway (which runs on top of Azure Load Balancer).

Application Gateway [runs on top of the Azure Load Balancer and adds Layer 7 HTTP routing capability](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4f2b38d-cb4d-4114-8904-584ff6660f85/azure-load-balancer-or-application-gateway?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)

From the [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq) docs:

> Q. What is Application Gateway?
>
> Azure Application Gateway is an Application Delivery Controller (ADC) as a service, offering various layer 7 load balancing capabilities for your applications. It offers highly available and scalable service, which is fully managed by Azure.
>
> Q. How does Application Gateway support HTTP/2?
>
> HTTP/2 protocol support is available to clients connecting to Application Gateway listeners only. The communication to backend server pools is over HTTP/1.1.
>
> By default, HTTP/2 support is disabled. The following Azure PowerShell code snippet example shows how you can enable it:

```
$gw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name test -ResourceGroupName hm
$gw.EnableHttp2 = $true
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
```

So in your specific case, you'd use HTTP/2 between the load balancer and customers, and HTTP/1.1 between the load balancr and your VMs.